# Undefined reference to vtable (C++)

Tags: c++

I am making an Entity class for my sfml game but I can't understand why the following code can't compile. I get an `undefined reference to vtable in Entity` error.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H
#include <string>
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Rect.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Time.hpp>

class Entity
{
public:
        Entity(std::string id, sf::Vector2f position, float rotation );
        virtual ~Entity() = 0;
        virtual sf::FloatRect getBoundingRect() const;
        virtual float getRadius() const;
        void UpdateVelocity(sf::Time);
        void UpdatePosition(sf::Time);
        void Update(sf::Time);
        float getRotation() const;
        sf::Vector2f getPosition() const;
        sf::Vector2f getVelocity() const;
        sf::Vector2f getAcceleration() const;


private:
        std::string mId;
        sf::Vector2f mPosition;
        float mRotation;
        sf::Vector2f mVelocity;
        sf::Vector2f mAcceleration;
};

#endif // ENTITY_H
```

and here is the cpp file:

```
#include "../include/Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(std::string id, sf::Vector2f position, float rotation)
        : mId(id)
        , mPosition(position)
        , mRotation(rotation)
{
}

Entity::~Entity()
{
}


void Entity::UpdateVelocity(sf::Time dt)
{
        mVelocity += mAcceleration;
}

void Entity::UpdatePosition(sf::Time dt)
{
        mPosition += mVelocity;
}

void Entity::Update(sf::Time dt)
{
        UpdateVelocity(dt);
        UpdatePosition(dt);
}

float Entity::getRotation() const
{
        return mRotation;
}

sf::Vector2f Entity::getPosition() const
{
        return mPosition;
}

sf::Vector2f Entity::getVelocity() const
{
        return mVelocity;
}

sf::Vector2f Entity::getAcceleration() const
{
        return mAcceleration;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the implementation of some virtual methods:

```
    virtual sf::FloatRect getBoundingRect() const;
    virtual float getRadius() const;
```

If you don't want your `Entity` class to implement these, declare them as pure virtual:

```
    virtual sf::FloatRect getBoundingRect() const = 0;
    virtual float getRadius() const = 0;
```

Note that, as commented by @JoachimIsaksson, it isn't completely obvious whether you need your destructor to be pure virtual. You have provided an empty implementation for it, but you still require derived types to implement it. It may be worth considering whether you need it to be pure virtual.

Comment: Thank you very much they were supposed to be declared as pure virtuals and I completely missed it!

Comment: @Veritas OK, I was adding that as an alternative.

Comment: @Veritas `~Entity()` is also declared pure virtual and implemented anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, but an empty virtual implementation isn't normally very useful so thought I'd point it out in case it wasn't intentional.

Comment: A pure virtual destructor **must** have its body defined - it still gets called after the derived destructors have run. The effect of making a function pure virtual is to force derived classes to override it. This is orthogonal to whether or not it has an implementation.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, good point. The question should be whether OP needs it to be pure virtual or not, not whether they need the implementation. Corrected.

Comment: Sometimes you want to keep a class abstract and you don't want any pure virtual functions. Declaring the destructor as pure virtual solves this so I tend to always add it on abstract classes for consistency.